# windbg: !chkimg -d nt - Error: Could not find image file for module

Tags: windbg

I'm trying to run the following command in windbg while in a local kernel debugging session:
`!chkimg -d nt`
And I'm getting this error:
`Error for nt: Could not find image file for the module. Make sure binaries are included in the symbol path.`
It would seem that the image file path (`.exepath`) has not been set but I have a perfectly valid path, and the symbols have been loaded correctly too (I followed the instructions here: http://www.debugging.tv/Frames/0x07/DebuggingTV_Frame_0x07.pdf). Interestingly if I run `!chkimg -d atapi` I get the correct output with no error.
Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Works just fine for me... What is your OS version? Do you have the right symbol path (including MS public symbol server: SRV*c:\debuggers\symbols\*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols)

Comment: Symbol path was absolutely fine. Turned out to be the WinDbg version! See my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok... after hours of mucking around with this, I realised that my version of WinDbg was a few versions behind (6.2.9200.16384). I was clutching at straws so I downloaded and installed the latest version (6.12.0002.633) and, hey presto, it worked! I've got no idea why it doesn't work in the old version (I think it's only just over a year old), but at least it's working now.

Comment: Thanks, it works. But 6.2.9200.16384 is a newer version then 6.12.0002.633 (they changed version numbering system).